# How to create main links like home ,services programatically?

Tags: routes

I am creating a new website in Drupal 7,but from my past efforts I tried adding main menu links(home,services,clients,blog etc)but all in vain!!

Can anyone tell me how to create main menu links programmatically or through admin interface?

Comment: go to `admin/structure/menu` and add the links to the menu you want

Comment: @wolverine, that is not very "programatically".

Comment: @FreeRadical He mentioned "programmatically or through **admin interface**"

Comment: @wolverine, fair enough - overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// You can use the following code to create a menu.

// Path.
$path = 'admin/structure/menu/manage/';
// Title of your menu.
$menu['title'] = 'My Another Menu';
// Description.
$menu['description'] = 'My Another Menu';

// Manu name like navigation, management which we have in drupal.
$menu_name = 'custommenu';
$menu['menu_name'] = $menu_name;

// Link title.
$link['link_title'] = 'My Another Menu';
// Link path.
$link['link_path'] = $path . $menu_name;
// Router path.
$link['router_path'] = $path;
// Module name.
$link['module'] = 'menu';
$link['plid'] = 0;

// Saves a menu link.
menu_link_save($link);
// Saves a custom menu.
menu_save($menu);

// After creating main menu. You can create links under it.
// Use the below code to create custom links.

$item_link = array(
  'link_path' => '<front>',
  'link_title' => 'Test link',
  'menu_name' => 'custommenu',
  'weight' => 0,
  'expanded' => 1,
);
// Creates custom link under main menu.
menu_link_save($item_link);
```